# TinyMCE Editor: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have aspx in that I am calling a ascx user control in that i am using tinymce editor. When I am trying to save data i am getting the error..

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (UserControl1$TextBox1="

fgh

fghj

I already check [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

I tried:

web.config I set

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
<@page validateRequest="false">
Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text)
encoding: "xml" // This is solving the prob. but Text is converting in HTML tag I don't want that
```

Please someone help me...

Answer (score 6):

You can also try adding the encoding attribute : **encoding: 'xml'**

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    encoding: 'xml' 
}); 
</script>
```

You can check this [link](http://myprogrammingblog.com/2012/03/05/how-to-setup-tinymce-using-asp-net-c-how-to-customize-tinymce-buttons/), it says :

> encoding: “xml”
>
> – solves  “A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected”,
>   which won’t allow you to submit the Web Form

Answer (score 3):

Add this to httpRuntime

```
< httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"  />
```

Comment: HttpRuntimeSection.RequestValidation looks like a backwards compatibility feature to me. Using [AllowHtml] on individual fields seems better

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't encode the string and store in your database and then just before displaying the encoded string you can simply decode it ?

Comment: for the first time I am able to save the data when i am using encoding: "xml", but again when i am unloading the data and trying to save same error is coming, I am storing the textbox text in a viewstate and assigning to hashtable also

Comment: Why are you using xml encoding can you not just use Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text) not in web.config but in c# code behind where you pull the value just before saving.

Comment: if i am not using the xml encoding the error is coming, and when i am clicking on btn click debug pointer is not going in that before that only error is showing

Comment: will be really useful if you could post some more of your code and the outputs you are seeing.